# Emulation problems with Paper Mario

Tags: emulation, nintendo-64, paper-mario

Has anyone successfully emulated PaperMario for N64?

I'm using Project64 1.6 on Windows 7

Using Jabo's video plugin there is lots of flickering which was really annoying so I tried Glide64. Which worked great everywhere, but was extremely slow going into battles. Rice did the same thing as Glide64, but would not render the whole battle animation, just go slow.

Has anyone successfully gotten these things to stop, or know of any settings I should tweak?

Comment: Have you tried PJ64 1.7?  And Glide64 shouldn't even work unless you have an old 3Dfx card, unless it doesn't refer to the Glide I'm familiar with. I have fond memories of UltraHLE with my Voodoo 2 and 3.

Comment: no i haven't. yeah you have to use a wrapper for it, which is why i think it runs slow. I have not, has it been publicly released yet?

Comment: Apparently not. I have a PJ64 installer from years ago labelled 1.7, I wonder if they later backed up and made it a 1.6 release. I'll try to experiment later and see what works for me, I do remember playing Paper Mario without problems.

Comment: i located a copy of it. It works perfectly. Well the battle animation doesn't render it just sorta flickers, but it doesn't slow down, or flicker on parts of the map so its great!

Comment: If you write that as an asnwer i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try PJ64 1.7.  I don't remember having problems with Paper Mario myself, although there's some question as to whether I really had the same 1.7 as the current beta version.

Answer (score 1):

N64 emulators as a whole are awful at proper graphics emulation. There are some workarounds, however. If you are intent on staying with plugin-based emulators, [GlideN64](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/gliden64-graphics-plugin) is currently under development and may fix many of the common woes with graphics plugins.

The other option is, surprisingly, running it through Dolphin as a Virtual Console ROM. As Dolphin has a much more reliable emulation platform, I've found it actually is a more faithful emulation, though it requires a much more powerful pc. [This link](https://forums.dolphin-emu.org/Thread-howto-extract-rom-from-a-virtual-console-game) gives a tutorial on how to set up the ROM for use with Dolphin, though it's much more involved than switching plugins.